# Filter XML in as3 by nodes

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

in Flash using as3 how can i filter an xml by node 
suppose that the xml has group node like below and i want the items where group=category1

```
group>category1 /group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var filteredXml:XMLList = myXml.(group == "category1");
trace(filteredXml);
```